# Can I have VideoView as a WebView background?

Tags: android, video, webview, background, android-videoview

Does anyone know how to maintain VideoView as WebView background?

My idea is to have a two layers on the screen. A WebView, in front of a VideoView (this View is going to have a video playing in immersive mode - Full Screen).

On the WebView I want to play animations when x position of the video is reached.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a `FrameLayout`, whose first child is `VideoView` and second child is `WebView`.

```
<FrameLayout>
    <VideoView />
    <WebView />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Ummm, I will try this. Thanks ;)